# What is the functional space of (general) Wavelet transform of squared-integrable functions?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, convolution, wavelets

Let $\psi(x) = \exp(-x^2)$. The (general) Wavelet transform $W: L^2(\mathbb R) \rightarrow X$ is  defined by
$$Wf(a, b) = b^{-1/2}\int_{x\in \mathbb R} f(x) \psi\left( \frac{x-a}{b}\right)dx$$
for $(a, b) \in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$.

My question is: What is the functional space $X$?

---

**NOTE:**

Note that the function $\psi$ above is a Gaussian-like function, which is not exactly a wavelet function. In general, a function $\psi$ is called a wavelet function if it satisfies 1) $\psi$ has compact support or at least fast decaying at infinity and 2) $\int_{x \in \mathbb R} \psi(x) dx=0$. The given function $\psi$ however only satisfies the first requirement. We therefore refer it as a "general" Wavelet transformation.

To have a clue for our question. Let's us consider a particular case, when $b=b_0$ is constant, then $Wf$ is just a function of $a$. In this case $$Wf \in X = C_0(\mathbb R).$$
Indeed, in this case, one can see that $Wf = b_0^{-1/2} f\star \psi(\cdot/b_0)$, i.e. $W$ is a simply a convolution operator. A (well-known?) fundamental result states that: *The convolution operator of two $L^2$ functions is $C_0$*. Hence $ Wf\in C_0(\mathbb R)$.

For the original question, numerical simulations also suggest that $X=C_0(\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R)$. It it correct?

Comment: Consider giving a look to these wikis: [Distribution_(mathematics)#Compact-Supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Distributions_with_compact_support_2) and [Gabor Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform)

Comment: While I do not know the answer to this I wouldn't be surprised if the solution to this problem could be found in Gröchenig's (quite mathematical & precise) book ["Foundations of Time-Frequency Analysis"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0003-1)

Answer (score 2):

Since $X = C_0(\mathbb R)$ satisfies the letter of your question, I assume you want the **smallest** such $X$, or in other words, the range of $W$.

First, your reasoning also applies when considering $Wf$ as a bivariate function, so you can in fact prove $Wf \in C_0(\mathbb R \times (0,\infty))$ (you have to exclude the case $b=0$).

There is more though: because your kernel is $C^\infty$ and all its derivatives are $L^\infty$, you can in fact show that $Wf$ is $C^\infty$. More than that, it is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \times \{z \in \mathbb C : \mathrm{Re}(z) > 0 \}$, see below.

Of course not all holomorphic functions on this domain are in the range of $Wf$; for example, by the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2)
$$ |Wf(a,b)| \leq \left(\int |f|^2 \right)^{1/2} $$
for every $(a,b)\in \mathbb R \times (0,\infty)$, so your function $Wf$ must be bounded on $\mathbb R \times (0,\infty)$ (it cannot be bounded as a complex function though). To establish the range of $W$, [define an inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform#Inverse_Gabor_transform) (that recovers $f$ from $Wf$) and see **which analytic functions are sent to $L^2$ functions by this inverse transform**.

As a final note, there is always the possibility that $L^2$ is not the best space to consider; for example, the Fourier transform is defined on [tempered distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Tempered_distributions), which are a much larger class of objects.

### Proof of holomorphicity (you can skip)

For simplicity I will only prove it when $a$ and $b$ are both real. To prove that a function is holomorphic, we need to prove that it is equal to its infinite Taylor series near any point $(a,b)$ of its domain of definition.

The first thing I want to do is define $Vf(a,b) = Wf(a,b^{-1})$. This makes the computations a bit easier without changing the conclusion.

Fix $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b>0$, and reparametrize it by $H(u,v) = Vf(a+u, b+v)$. Then
\begin{align}
H(u,v) &= (b+v)^{-1/2} \int f(x) e^{-(b+v)^2 (x-a-u)^2} dx \\
&= (b+v)^{-1/2} e^{-(b+v)^2 (a+u)^2}\int f(x) e^{-(b+v)^2 \left[ x^2 - (a+u)x \right]} dx
\end{align}
The function $v \mapsto (b+v)^{-1/2} e^{-(b+v)^2 (a+u)^2}$ is indeed holomorphic for $|v|<b$. If we prove that the integral is holomorphic as a function of $(u,v)$, the conclusion follows. This integral equals
\begin{align}
&\int f(x) e^{-b^2 x^2} e^{-((b+v)^2+b^2)x^2 + (b+v)^2 (a+u)x} dx \\
&= \int \sum_{n\geq 0}  f(x) e^{-b^2 x^2} \frac 1 {n!} \left(\left(-(b+v)^2+ b^2\right)x^2 + (b+v)^2 (a+u)x\right)^n dx   \\
&= \int \sum_{n,j,k\geq 0} f(x) e^{-b^2 x^2} c_{n,j,k} u^j v^k P_{n,j,k}(x)  dx . \qquad (1)
\end{align}
where the $P_{n,j,k}$ are polynomials in $x$: the first line is the expansion of the exponential, the second is the binomial theorem – and by writing down the binomial theorem explicitely, we can prove the **very useful fact** that for every $u,v,x$ with $|v|<b$,
\begin{align}
& \sum_{j,k\geq 0} \left| c_{n,j,k} u^j v^k P_{n,j,k}(x) \right| \leq \frac 1 {n!} \left(\left(b^2-(b-|v|)^2\right)x^2 + (b+|v|)^2 (|a|+|u|)|x|\right)^n .
\end{align}
Can we exchange the sums and integral in $(1)$? Let us check the condition of [Fubini’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem): for $|v|<b$,
\begin{align}
&\int \sum_{j,k,n\geq 0} |f(x)| e^{-b^2 x^2} \left| c_{n,j,k} u^j v^k P_{n,j,k}(x) \right| dx \\
&\leq \int \sum_{n\geq 0} |f(x)| e^{-b^2 x^2} \frac 1 {n!} \left(\left(-(b+|v|)^2+ b^2\right)x^2 + (b+|v|)^2 (|a|+|u|)|x|\right) dx \\
&= \int |f(x)| \exp\left( -b^2 x^2+ |v|(2b+|v|) x^2 + (b+|v|)^2 (|a|+|u|)|x| \right) dx \\
&\leq \left( \int |f|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\int \exp\left( -2(b-|v|)^2 x^2+ 2 (b+|v|)^2 (|a|+|u|)|x| \right) dx \right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
where we used the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) in the last step. We can check that the second integral is finite, meaning the function in $(*)$ is integrable, so we can exchange the sums and integral in any way we want:
$$ (1) = \sum_{j,k\geq 0} h_{j,k} u^j v^k $$
with
$$ h_{j,k} := \sum_{n\geq 0}\int f(x) e^{-b^2 x^2} c_{n,j,k} P_{n,j,k}(x) dx . $$
This means that $(1)$, and thus $H$, is holomorphic for $(u,v)$ close to zero, or that $Vf$ is holomorphic close to $(a,b)$. Since this is true for every $(a,b) \in \mathbb R \times (0,\infty)$, it means that $Vf$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of that set.

Comment: thank you for your valuable observations about the spaces in which $Wf$ exists, so 1 up vote for now. Your statement that "you can in fact prove $Wf\in C_0(\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty))$" caught my attention. This is not trivial for me. As you may have noticed in my previous attempt, I struggled to prove this without success. It is great if you can provide a more detailed explanation/proof on this observation.

Comment: Sure thing - you can use the same proof, with minor adaptation: by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$ |Wf(a,b) - Wf(c,d)| = \left|\int \left(b^{-1/2}\psi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right) - d^{-1/2}\psi\left(\frac{x-c}{d}\right)\right) f(x) dx\right|
 \leq \left(\int f^2\right)^{1/2} \left( \int \left|b^{-1/2}\psi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right) - d^{-1/2}\psi\left(\frac{x-c}{d}\right)\right| dx \right)^{1/2} $$
and you can prove that the second integral converges to 0 as $|a-c| + |b-d| \to 0$.

Comment: According to your comment, $Wf$ is a continuous function and this is clear for me. However, the main difficulty here is to prove that $Wf \in C_0$, ie it must vanish on the "boundary" of $R\times (0, +\infty)$.

Comment: When $b\to 0$ I do not expect $Wf(a,b)$ to vanish: on the contrary, in some sense it will converge to $f$, which is non-zero. When $|a|\to \infty$ on the other hand, I am confident that $Wf(a,b)\to 0$.

Comment: For fixed $a$, we see that $b^{-1} \psi((x-a)/b)$ is a scaling of Gaussian distribution which is of finite mass. Therefore, when $b\rightarrow 0$, then $b^{-1/2} Wf \rightarrow f(a)$, thus  $ Wf \rightarrow b^{1/2} f(a)\rightarrow 0$. However, I have no clue if both $a, b$ are moving.

Comment: Good point, I had failed to see that it was $b^{-1/2}$, not $b^{-1}$! This means that in my answer, any $g = Wf$ is analytic with limit zero when $b\to 0$.